# Time Derivative of a Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, positive-definite

Suppose we have a positive definite symmetric matrix $\mathbf V(0) \in \mathbb S^{n}_{++}$, which changes with time according to the following equation,

$\dot{\mathbf V}(t) = \mathbf A \mathbf V(t) + \mathbf V(t) \mathbf A^\text{T}$,

where $\mathbf A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is an arbitrary constant matrix.

I would like be able to claim that $\mathbf V(t) \succ \mathbf 0$ for all $t \geq 0$.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least *one* solution of the above differential equation is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf V(t) = e^{\mathbf A t} \mathbf V(0) e^{\mathbf A^\text{T} t}.
\end{equation}
Since $e^{\mathbf A^\text{T} t}= (e^{\mathbf A t})^\text{T}$, this can be written as
\begin{equation}
\mathbf V(t) = e^{\mathbf A t} \mathbf V(0) (e^{\mathbf A t})^\text{T}.
\end{equation}
The matrix $e^{\mathbf A t}$ is nonsingular. Thus, $\mathbf V(t) \succ 0$.

Comment: If someone could convince me that $\mathbf V(t) = e^{\mathbf A t} \mathbf V(0) e^{\mathbf A^\text{T} t}$ is the ONLY solution to the above ODE, that would be awesome.

Comment: The properties of the matrix exponential can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)

Comment: It should be fairly easy to prove that the right hand side is Lipschitz in $V$ and hence fulfils the requirements of Picard-Lindelöf.

Comment: My friend Peter asserts that the linearity and homogeneity of the ODE ensures uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: Well, that a priori only states that the solution space is a vector space. You do actually __need__ Picard-Lindelöf for uniqueness.